# Difference between two entropic states of the same variable

Tags: terminology, entropy, information-theory

I am interested in finding the difference of entropy between two states of the same variable. The probability distribution associated with the variable X changes at each discrete point in time *t* by an increment in *p(i)*. The current state is therefore always an update of the former state as we advance each step along the message. I am applying the equation below, where *t* is a multiplier to make the difference of entropy proportional to time (this is part of a study on statistical memory, so such proportionality gives a weight to events happening further along in a message).

$I=t(H(X)_{t+1}-H(X)_t)$

My question is: what is *I*? I am inclined to call it information gain or information divergence, but the literature seems to be highly divergent (no pun intended) on the nomenclature. Of course *I* could be something different entirely (covariance?).

This is a question from someone with no formal background in statistics or information theory, so please bear with me while I try to make sense of my problem. Any clarification or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What are you actually looking for?  The evident answer to "what is $I$" is that it's a weighted difference of entropies!  What additional, useful information would any other possible answer supply?  What actually is the "problem" to which you refer?

Comment: Dear @whuber, thanks for your reply. My problem is, well, how to name the thing. _I_ seems to be an instance of a KL divergence or information gain, depending on the source I check. Would either be the case or is this too long a shot? Finding the difference between contiguous entropy states is useful for my practical purposes – but if this is something already backed up by a conceptual framework, I'll have something specific to look up.

Comment: have you heard of transfer entropy? It is the entropy of the current value of $X$ conditioned on its previous values, so it must have some correspondence to your formula, which is only one-lagged, and probably more preferable for your application https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_entropy

Comment: I'm sorry for the naive questions, but so far the metric does not make sense to me: 1) If you expect the difference of consecutive entropies to increase, that could be either due to the fact that entropy itself increases super-linearly, in which case you can just use entropy itself as a metric, or it oscillates, but in that case you need to take absolute value somewhere, as differences will change sign. 2) Do you know for sure that entropy should grow linearly with time? If not, why not just calculate the entropy, and see if it grows with time, for example, using correlation or spearmann rank?